# VBA Opening a Word document from info in excell cell but dont have full file name

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a list of document IDS in excel each in an individaul cell.

In the same folder as my excel sheet are the documents which are all named something like 0001 Issue 2, 0002 Issue 1 etc.

Currently I have it set up with a command button where the user selects the cell they want hits the button and it opens, however I have to have the full name of the file in the cell e.g. 0002 Issue 1.

I ideally would like it to work if just the first 4 digits of the file name was in the cell e.g. 0001 so that if a new issue is released the file doesnt need to be updated.

Ive tried using * as wild cards in lots of differnt locations, none of which worked for me. I also tried instead of using the TextBox1.Value I typed the first 4 digits and then * and that didnt work.

Also if it matters I cant guarantee how many characters will come after the first 4 digits, it can vary.

This is what I have so far with regards to the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.application")
wordapp.documents.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & TextBox1.Value & ".docx"
wordapp.Visible = True

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Open` method doesn't support wildcards, so you need to first use (eg) `Dir()` to identify a matching file (ie. file name starts with textbox content and has a docx extension).

Edit: added handling multiple matched files

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim allFiles As Collection, f, txt
    
    txt = TextBox1.Value
    'find any matching files....
    Set allFiles = FileMatches(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\", _
                               txt & "*.docx")
    
    If allFiles.Count > 0 Then        'any files found?
        With CreateObject("word.application")
            .Visible = True
            For Each f In allFiles    'loop and open found files
                .documents.Open pth & f
            Next f
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No file found with name beginning '" & txt & "'", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub

'return all files whose name matches `pattern` in folder `fPath`
Function FileMatches(fPath As String, pattern As String) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f
    If Right(fPath, 1) <> "\" Then fPath = fPath & "\" 'ensure ends with "\"
    f = Dir(fPath & pattern, vbNormal)
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        rv.Add fPath & f 'add full path to the collection
    Loop
    Set FileMatches = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you!! This works!! If I wanted it to open multiple files that start with the same code is this possible?